# Create git branches from commits

Tags: git

I have `develop` branch in git repository.

`git log` shows something similar to:

```
commit 111
    Commit Last
commit 222
    Commit Last-1
commit 333
    Commit Last-2
```

What I want to do is:

```
1. Revert to #333
2. Create a branch Branch-111 which will contain #333 + #111
3. Create a branch Branch-222 which will contain #333 + #222
```

These new branches should only changes from #333 and one of specified branches.

I tried to create 2 patches. But I can not apply them on #333 - I have multiple `patch does not apply`

What is the proper way to solve this task?

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch branch222 develop~1 # this branch can be kept as is
git checkout -b branch111 develop~2
git cherry-pick develop # apply 111 change
git branch -f develop develop~2 # take back develop 2 revisions
```

That should do

Answer (score 0):

One way you could handle this is:

```
git checkout -b Branch-111 <hash of "commit 111">
git rebase -i HEAD~~~
# delete line for "commit 222"

git checkout -b Branch-222 <hash of "commit 222">
```